# Using re.form= in predict.merMod() for a lmer() model

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

If I fit a model with a random-intercept and random-slope then use `predict.Mermod` with `re.form = ~ (1|Subject)`, my gut told me this would be the same as fitting a random-intercept only model and using `predict.merMod` with the default `re.form=NULL`. This is not the case.

```
library("lme4")
library("ggplot2")
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), data=sleepstudy)
fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data=sleepstudy)

sleepstudy$pr1 <- predict(fm1, sleepstudy)
sleepstudy$pr1b <- predict(fm1, sleepstudy, re.form = ~(1|Subject))
sleepstudy$pr2 <- predict(fm2, sleepstudy)
```

I thought `pr1b` and `pr2` would the same. They are not. The intercepts for `pr2` are more spread out than the intercepts for `pr1b`. Can you give a brief explanation as to why they are different?

```
ggplot(data=sleepstudy, aes(Days, pr1)) + geom_line(aes(color = Subject))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data=sleepstudy, aes(Days, pr1b)) + geom_line(aes(color = Subject))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data=sleepstudy, aes(Days, pr2)) + geom_line(aes(color = Subject))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that dropping random effects from predictions does not re-estimate the reduced model, it just sets the other random effects to 0, so it is still "fully conditional".

In the first model, for which you controlled for days and random slopes and intercepts, each individual has three contributions to their predicted value when interpolating data: the fixed effects as well as the two random effects. For observation 3, subject 308,, you find reaction = 250.8006 and days=2. fm1 generates fixed effects

```
> fixef(fm1)
(Intercept)        Days 
  251.40510    10.46729
```

So the response form

```
>  predict(fm1, re.form=NA)[3]
       3 
272.3397
```

is equal to

```
>  251.40510  +  10.46729 *2
[1] 272.3397
```

The prediction when you don't use your random effects even though you estimated them.

The random effects are:

```
> ranef(fm1)
$Subject
    (Intercept)        Days
308   2.2585649   9.1989720
309 -40.3985805  -8.6197025
310 -38.9602496  -5.4488793
330  23.6905015  -4.8143318
331  22.2602054  -3.0698950
332   9.0395269  -0.2721708
333  16.8404330  -0.2236247
334  -7.2325801   1.0745762
335  -0.3336950 -10.7521592
337  34.8903539   8.6282834
349 -25.2101132   1.1734147
350 -13.0699587   6.6142053
351   4.5778359  -3.0152573
352  20.8635944   3.5360130
369   3.2754533   0.8722165
370 -25.6128726   4.8224651
371   0.8070399  -0.9881551
372  12.3145406   1.2840295
```

So adding 2.2585649  to this prediction is just using the intercept but not the slope, and it gives you:

```
>  251.40510  +  10.46729 *2 + 2.2585649 
[1] 274.5982
```

Which is the same as:

```
> predict(fm1, re.form=(~1|Subject))[3]
       3 
274.5982
```

Now the trick to understanding all this is realizing that specifying more complex random effects will fundamentally change the lower level effects you're estimating:

A simple comparison of

fixef(fm1) fixef(fm2) and ranef(fm1) and ranef(fm2) will show you this.

Comment: Thanks, Adam! As a follow up: Say I trained my model on Days 1-9, then wanted to predict Day 10. Should I investigate whether `pr1b` does a better job of prediction than `pr2`? Or should I assume `pr1b` is basically 'invalidated' since I am fitting the model one way, but then twisting it a bit to get predictions?

Comment: @hossibley if the model you want is both random slopes and random intercepts, then `fm1` is the better model. Otherwise, I would fit `fm2` since the fixed effects will provide an overall better fit by not accounting for random slopes.